# Installing Footheme

Tags: theming

I submitted this as [an issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2465647) to Adaptive Themes over a month ago and haven't had any response, so I'd like to ask the community for help with it.

I've selected [Pixture Reloaded](https://www.drupal.org/project/pixture_reloaded) as the theme for a multi-site installation, intending to use the [Footheme](https://www.drupal.org/project/footheme) subtheme with it. I have installed Pixture Reloaded and have been using it. I need to tweak some things, so I need Footheme, but there's a problem with the installation instructions.

In the Footheme ReadMe file, the second last paragraph says, "In footheme_preprocess_html() you will find some stuff ... follow those instructions carefully - they are easy and involve renaming some CSS files to match your theme name." I don't see what that's talking about. The file, "template.php" has a function definition for "footheme_preprocess_html()", but it's empty. There are no significant instructions in the rest of that file either. This may be important because I need to make some changes to CSS, so I don't want to move forward without knowing that I have all the proper instructions. Can someone tell me what I need to do?

Thank you.

Comment: footie me is an alias for your subthemes name. look at  https://www.drupal.org/node/225125 and read the text again after you ar tough with the article.  You'll see that it is very simple if you understand what to do. Maybe that's why you don't have got an answer in the issue queue.

Comment: This also may solve the problem.  http://adaptivethemes.com/documentation/footheme-starter-coloarble-sub-theme-for-corolla-sky-and-pixture-reloaded